# Solutions $\in \mathbb N$ for $x^2+xy-y^2=c$ where $0<c\leq 10$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am currently stuck at $c=3$. Here's what I figured out for $c=2$ (hopefully correct):

> Since $x^2+xy-y^2$ is even only if x and y are even, we can write it as $$(2m)^2+2m2n-(2n)^2=2$$ which means that there would have to be a solution $\in \mathbb N$ to $$2(m^2+mn-n^2)=1$$
>   which is not possible since the bracketed term is always whole. For c=1 there are infinitely many solutions $(x_k,y_k)$ starting with $(1,0)$ and further  $(x_{k+1},y_{k+1})=(x_k+y_k,x_k+2y_k)$.

Now for 3 I chose the same apporach:

$$(2m+1)^2+(2m+1)(2n+1)-(2n+1)^2=3$$
$$\cdots$$
$$2(m^2+mn-n^2)=1+n-3m$$

So I do get the original term, which looks useful, but I don't see how to get more out of it—provided there is a way. Any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I found some advanced tricks on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78361/which-integers-take-the-form-x2-xy-y2) and some other sites, but the author of this problem supposes one to solve this with basic methods. The key information seems to be that if I have one solution, I can generate all of them.

Comment: Note, this equation is equivalent to $(2x+y)^2-5y^2=4c$.

Comment: For $3$ you didn't check the case when one of $x,y$ is even and the other is odd.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I saw that on MathOverflow, but the autor supposes one to solve this with basically only the information contained above, so I didn't want to use it. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @user236182 Alright, I guess I'll have to ditch that method for 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ x^2+xy-y^2 = c $$
is equivalent to:
$$ (2x+y)^2-5y^2 = 4c\tag{1} $$
but for $c=3$ there are no solutions, since $12\equiv 2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{5}$.

Comment: At this point of the book I am not supposed to know anything about quadratic residues—do you happen to know of a more basic method?

Comment: @Grantwalzer: that is just a nomenclature issue. The impossibility of $(1)$ is a consequence of the fact that there are no squares of the form $5k+2$. That is easy to prove, even without making an explicit mention of "quadratic residues" - try squaring the first natural numbers and check if the last digit is ever $2$ or $7$.

Comment: @Grantwalzer $(5k\pm 1)^2=5(5k^2\pm 2k)+1$ and $(5k\pm 2)^2=5(5k^2\pm 4k)+4$, therefore the only squares mod $5$ are $0,1,4$.

Comment: @user236182 I would have never come up with that myself—thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

For $c=3$, by checking every case $(x,y)\pmod 3$, you'll see that both $x$ and $y$ have to be $0\pmod 3$. Then, setting $x=3m,y=3n$ gives
$$(3m)^2+(3m)(3n)-(3n)^2=3\Rightarrow 3(m^2+mn-n^2)=1,$$
which is impossible.